# Node Non-Blocking Data Processing

Tags: node.js, express, node-serialport

I have a Node process that handles both incoming data packets (once per second) from a microcontroller using node-serialport and incoming http requests from a browser using Express.  The data is stored and accessed from a Mongo database.

This is the code that handles the data from the serial port:

```
// Handles incoming chunks of binary data from the device.
serialport.on('data',function(data) {
    // Store data packet in the database
    receive(data);
});
```

This is the code that handles requests from a browser:

```
// Serves data dynamically via AJAX.
app.get('/fetch', function(req,res) { return fetch(req,res); });
```

Both `receive()` and `fetch()` log to the console.

To summarize, `fetch()` gets up to 8M database entries and boils them all down to up to 1000 data points times 7 data sets, then sends them over the network.  The problem is the "boiling down" processing in the `fetch()` function can sometimes take a while.  To exaggerate this effect, I used the npm sleep package and put `sleep(2)` at the beginning of `fetch()`.

Sure enough, while `fetch()` was processing the data, I no longer saw the logging that was part of `receive()`.  When the processing was over, two data packets came in almost simultaneously and were processed.  After reading about Node being single threaded, I get why this is happening.  While my lines of code are being sequentially executed, Node is not available to receive data on the serial port.  The timing isn't good, but the fact that they are ending up on the server is a good sign.  When I upped the sleep time from 2 seconds to 10 seconds, however, the behavior was the same.  The process hung and I got no data packet logging for 10 seconds, and after 10 seconds I got TWO data packets almost simultaneously (not ten?).  So maybe the implementation of node-serialport has an internal buffer that can only hold two of my data packets?? I don't know, but I'm curious.  Its sort of a sub-topic to this question, but any insight as to why I get two data packets after my processing is done no matter how long `fetch()` takes would be appreciated

This is my MAIN question:  Is there a way/package to split up the processing into chunks that themselves are blocking because of Node's single threaded nature, but leave room for receiving data on the serial port in between chunks?  Or do these two separate tasks require two separate node processes spawned from the parent process?

Comment: Node is asynchronous, no synchronous.  The number of threads is irrelevant.  If it's taking too long for node to return, there's some other problem.

Comment: Is it against the Node paradigm to do time-heavy processing?  Should I offload it to some other process?

Comment: Yeah, Node is just a "receiver." If you have heavy-lifting, it should stay off the Node thread.

Comment: it should stay off the node server process. you can spawn worker processes though and send messages.